# Loading of TableRows and TextViews into TableLayout after onCreate

Tags: java, android

I would like to load **TableRows** with **TextViews** into the table outside of oncreate.
It should look like that.

[image]

```
    TableLayout tableLayout;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sec);

            tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.itemTable);
    
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
            tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    
            TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            tv.setText("Dynamic Textview");
            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    
            tr.addView(tv);
    
            tableLayout.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
```

The problem is that I want to do the whole thing outside of the oncreate function. The rows and text views should only be added at runtime. If I do it outside then the added elements are rendered but not displayed. Is it even possible to load that outside of onCreate?

The xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemTable"
        android:layout_width="703dp"
        android:layout_height="241dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The function i want to work with:

```
public void setView () {

     TableRow tr = new TableRow(getContext());
     tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
         tv.setText("Dynamic Textview");
         tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(tv);
     }

     tr.invalidate();
     tableLayout.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

     tableLayout.invalidate();

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke `postInvalidate()` on the TableLayout or TableRow after their being loaded.